# How to make canvas splitted into 2 pages or more without getting cut off?

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas, jspdf

I have an invoice pdf containing a table rows which can increase, i know exactly how to add pages with jsPDF but the issue is im getting my image cut off and this is really annoying when you have dynamic content to print.
How to split my canvas image without getting it cut ? is there a solution ?
PS : i dont want my canvas to fit entirely in one PDF page because i can loose the quality of my image and it become crowded specially when the user has many invoice lines

Here is a screen of my resulted pdf :

[image]

TypeScript :

```
public convertToPDF() {
    const data = document.getElementById('contentToConvert');
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
        this.imgWidth = 200;
        this.imgHeight = (canvas.height * this.imgWidth / canvas.width);
        this.pageHeight = 295;
        this.heightLeft = this.imgHeight;
        const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4', true);
        this.position = 5;
        pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 5, this.position, this.imgWidth, this.imgHeight, '', 'FAST');
        this.heightLeft -= this.pageHeight;

        while (this.heightLeft >= 0) {
            this.position = this.heightLeft - this.imgHeight;
            pdf.addPage();
            pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 5, this.position, this.imgWidth, this.imgHeight);
            this.heightLeft -= this.pageHeight;
        }
        pdf.save('Facture' + '-' + this.client.nomRepresentant + this.facture.dateFacturation.format('YYYYMM') + '.pdf');
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello, did you got the solution? I am still searching for this

Comment: im no longer using jspdf, i use iText and thats a way better :)